# Where is setPreempted in actionlib documentation detailled implementation?

Tags: ros, wiki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I cannot find any notice of setPreempted in the wiki page http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib/DetailedDescription.

I would be glad to add it myself, but don't trust myself.

Gaël

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187421/where-is-setpreempted-in-actionlib-documentation-detailled-implementation?/) by [galou](https://answers.ros.org/users/14171/galou/) on ROS Answers with karma: 265 on 2014-07-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I maybe have an answer to myself. actionlib Detailled Description page is about ActionServer not SimpleActionServer.

---

Originally posted by [galou](https://answers.ros.org/users/14171/galou/) with karma: 265 on 2014-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0